# RegEx - Time Validation ((h)h:mm)

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/^\d{1,2}[:][0-5][0-9]$/
```

is what I have. this limits minutes to 00-59. It does not, however, limit hours to between 0 and 12. For similarity and uniformity I would like to do this with RegEx alone if possible.

Further-more I would like the first digit to be optional. i.e. 09:30 accepted as well as 9:30. I played around with ranges, but something out of range is always acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/^(10|11|12|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

I don't think that you want 0:50 as a valid time either.

Comment: Other way could be : /^(1[0|1|2]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you are working in 12 hour time, 0 is not a valid hour and should also be excluded (as pointed out by Jon).  Here is a basic solution:

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

A 24-hour time regex matcher that works similarly:

```
/^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/
```

Answer (score 12):

The 0 - 9 and 10 - 12 cases need to be treated separately. (The two rules can be combined with `|`.)

```
/^(?:0?\d|1[012]):[0-5]\d$/
```

Here

- `(?:…)` is a non-capturing group
- `x|y` means match either pattern
- `0?\d` matches 0 - 9 or 00 - 09
- `1[012]` matches 10 - 12.

Comment: What about a 24 Hour clock?

Answer (score 10):

For folks looking for 24h format matching,

hh:mm:ss or h:mm:ss :

```
status = /^(2[0-3]|[0-1]?[\d]):[0-5][\d]:[0-5][\d]$/.test(timestr)
```

hh:mm or h:mm :

```
status = /^(2[0-3]|[0-1]?[\d]):[0-5][\d]$/.test(timestr)
```

This site is great for testing out: https://www.regexpal.com/

Addedum: Explanation for completeness:

- `^` : start of string, `$` : end of string. So we put the expression in a `^..$` block to ensure there's nothing outside of our pattern.
- `(2[0-3]|[0-1]?[\d])` : translates to `2[0-3]` OR `[0-1]?[\d]`
- `2[0-3]` : 20, 21, 22, 23
- `[0-1]?[\d]` : 0 or 1 or nothing (`?`) followed by any single digit(`\d`). So, this works for numbers from 0 to 19.
- `:` just that character
- `[0-5][\d]` : number from 00 to 59. Note: this won't tolerate single-digit in the mm place.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks!!! I use this Javascript code now:

`function Check_arrival(time) {
            //Assuming you are working in 12 hour time, 0 is not a valid
            var patt = new RegExp("^(0?[1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]$");
            var res = patt.test(time);
            return res;
        }`

res=true|false

Comment: good that you give the javascript RegExp class way to do this as the OP is tagged as javascript. still like the answer @Trey Hunner gave for its 24 hour consideration.

Answer (score 0):

**This is perfect:  ^0?([0-9][0-2]?):[0-5][0-9]$**

Note: 12 Hr Clock Only

For Times like:
0:01- 12:59

or

00:01 - 12:59

Comment: Sorry this is the perfect one :)       (([0-9][0-2]?)|([0][0-9])):[0-5][0-9]$

Comment: 00:00  - 12:59   or     0:00 - 12:59

Answer (score 0):

`^(([0-9]{1})|([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1})|([2]{1}[0-3]{1}))(([:]{1})?)(([0-5]{1}[0-9]?)?)$`

- 29:30 <- invalid
- 9:21 <- valid
- 13:25 <- valid
- 19:01 <- valid
- 19:62 <- invalid
- 24:00 <- invalid
- 23:59 <- valid
- 00:00 <- valid
- 1 <- valid (can be sanitized to 01:00)
- 20 <- valid (can be sanitized to 20:00)
- 20: <- valid (can be sanitized to 20:00)
- 20:5 <- valid  (can be sanitized to 20:50)

`^(([0-9]{1})|([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1})|([2]{1}[0-3]{1}))([:]{1})([0-5]{1}[0-9]{1})$`

- 29:30 <- invalid
- 9:21 <- valid
- 13:25 <- valid
- 19:01 <- valid
- 19:62 <- invalid
- 24:00 <- invalid
- 23:59 <- valid
- 00:00 <- valid
- 1  <- invalid
- 20  <- invalid
- 20:  <- invalid
- 20:5  <- invalid