# Time entry validation in a HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms

I'm trying to add Date validation to a HTML form.  I want the date entered to be in the format `HH:MM:SS` not `HH:MM`.

If I enter date in the wrong format (e.g. `HH:MM`) then an Alert should show saying:

> "Date time format should be HH:MM:SS."

Please can you help me to correct my code so that it does this?
Here is my code in JavaScript:

```
if (date.match(regex pattern)) {
    alert("Valid date");
} else {
    alert("Invalid date: date should be in HH:MM:SS format!");
}
```

What is the correct way to validate the Time entered?

Comment: `/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/` if it's irrelevant which digits are entered, as long as it maches the hh:mm:ss pattern

Comment: @treegarden when i use in between (/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/) it is not consider in code or regex pattern why?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx - Time Validation ((h)h:mm)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732799/regex-time-validation-hhmm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This test HH:MM:SS pattern without testing about real hours, minutes and seconds:

HTML Code:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="text" id="date" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
function validate() {
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    if (date.match(/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/)) {
        alert("Valid date");
    } else {
        alert("Invalide date: dat should be in HH:MM:SS format!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can try it online here: http://jsfiddle.net/OscarGarcia/fow3htwz/1/

Remember: number of seconds and minutes are not tested! Someone could try to introduce this incorrect time: 43:87:91 and will (bad) pass the pattern!

### Edit: testing hours, minutes and seconds ranges

This code works like a charm :) http://jsfiddle.net/OscarGarcia/fow3htwz/2/

```
function validate() {
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    if (date.match(/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/)) {
        alert("Valid date");
    } else {
        alert("Invalide date: dat should be in HH:MM:SS format!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

### New edit using test instead match

Try it online: http://jsfiddle.net/OscarGarcia/fow3htwz/4/

```
function validate() {
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
    var pattern = /^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/;
    if (pattern.test(date)) {
        alert("Valid date");
    } else {
        alert("Invalide date: dat should be in HH:MM:SS format!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you. This is exact answer that I was loking for date validation. :-)

Comment: You're welcome! I had a mistake. I forgot test end of string with $ at the end of test pattern. I'll update my answer :)

Comment: It would be better to use `date.test()` instead of `date.match()` in that case,  since `date.test()` only checks if a string matches the pattern and returns a boolean, while `date.match()` searches a string for matches and returns them in an array.

Comment: Thanks @treegarden , probably he needs to validate the form and will parse the data in server side (PHP, ASP, ect), he don't need that info in client side so test will do the work better. There is a new update in my code allowing to test hours, minutes and seconds ranges. I'll update it again to add your contribution.